# Firefox Bug: Extra space in <select> dropdown due to chinese characters

Tags: firefox, html-select, chinese-locale

In Firefox 17, I am seeing extra space in the `<select>` dropdown.  The problem is triggered when the option list goes over 20 items.   See the screenshot here

[image]

I have fiddled with it for a while, reducing the `<select>` to a single Chinese character, see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4LDFU/4/

```
<form>
21 items (note blank space in dropdown)
<select  size="1"><option selected="selected" value="0">所有類別 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</option><option value="11450">服裝、鞋及配件</option><option value="14675">手機、通訊產品</option><option value="293">電子產品及電器</option><option value="58058">電腦及網絡</option><option value="625">數碼相機、攝影器材</option><option value="281">珠寶首飾及鐘錶</option><option value="220">玩具及個人愛好</option><option value="11700">家居生活</option>
    <option value="142313">Games</option><option value="45099">電影音樂</option><option value="1">收藏品</option><option value="260">郵票</option><option value="11116">錢幣</option><option value="888">體育、休閒及旅遊</option><option value="9800">汽車</option><option value="12576">商業及工業</option><option value="20081">古董</option><option value="267">書籍</option><option value="26395">健康及美容</option><option value="99">其他物品及服務</option></select>

<br><br>20 items (remove any one option, and blank space is gone)
<select  size="1">
    <option value="11450">服裝、鞋及配件</option>
    <option value="11450">服裝、鞋及配件</option>
    <option value="14675">手機、通訊產品</option>
    <option value="293">電子產品及電器</option>
    <option value="58058">電腦及網絡</option>
    <option value="625">數碼相機、攝影器材</option>
    <option value="220">玩具及個人愛好</option>
    <option value="11700">家居生活</option>
    <option value="142313">Games</option>
    <option value="45099">電影音樂</option>
    <option value="1">收藏品</option>
    <option value="260">郵票</option>
    <option value="11116">錢幣</option>
    <option value="888">體育、休閒及旅遊</option>
    <option value="9800">汽車</option>
    <option value="12576">商業及工業</option>
    <option value="20081">古董</option>
    <option value="267">書籍</option>
    <option value="26395">健康及美容</option>
    <option value="99">其他物品及服務</option>
</select>

<br><br>21 items again (stripped to one HK character, blank space remains)
<select  size="1">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>產</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
</select>
```

​

Any thoughts?  It only appears in Firefox.  In Chrome a scrollbar appears at 21 items, making me think its a bug with Firefox's calculation for the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

Replace: `所有類別` by `所有分类` (Chinese (Simplified))

Comment: Thanks for the help Guiherme -- no dice with the change, same problem.  You can remove all CN characters, save one.. and get the problem.

Comment: BTW folks.. New discovery: It appears that only ONE CN character is causing the problem -- 產 -- If you remove this from the two places it occurs in the first <select>, the problem is gone.

Comment: It really should be a bug in Firefox. Have you thought about reporting with FeedBack? I tested with every character in `Simplified` and failed too. (+1 for his discovery.)

Comment: It seems to be a problem between these two sentences: `手機、通訊產品` and `電子產品及電器`, and not only with the character you mentioned.

Comment: Good idea Guilherme.. Mozilla bug created here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820921